# Proper workspace organisation

Tags: macos

**Intro**

I am a big fun of Linux. I am going to change my job and will be forced to use MacOS. I know I need to get used to many new things and admit "MacOS way and philosophy" in general. Also I know it is better to agree to some things than try to change them.

**Problem**

I spend hours in front of my laptop and, obviously, I have to use it for my private needs. For this purpose I use two *activities* in KDE: *Private*, *Corporate*. The first one contains all my private and the second one contains all my corporate apps. When I share my screen I don't care about sensitive data between those two activities - my colleagues don't see my private conversations and my family doesn't see my job related staff. Very useful.

**User case**

I am heaving a zoom call with my team while my wife is visiting a Mall. She may ask me about some things and I just jump into *Private* activity by Win + Tab, give clarifications about her question and jump back.

I am having some free time and decided to looking for a new washing machine. So, on my Private activity I create Excel document, where listed all options I have found during my search. In case suddenly call, I just jump into *Corporate* activity and participate in the discussion without any worries about screen sharing or data loosing - everything stay where I left it.

The point is that I can keep my private apps active and be able to use them quickly without worries if someone see something that he shouldn't (conversations, emails, accounts details, etc)

**Question**

Is there a way to organize my workspace similarly on MacOS?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they're called "spaces" in macOS. Here's a user guide from Apple about using them: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/work-in-multiple-spaces-mh14112/mac

There are a bunch of demo videos out there. Here's one showing it in action: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uWhZdO6oL8w

Comment: I am an active user of virtual desktops and use 3 VD on every activity. So, in my case it would be 6 spaces, which isn't quite pretty. Furthermore, all my private windows will appear on Cmd + Tab or Mission control which is bad as well. So, this solution doesn't split two environments completely. If you play tetris on your Private activity everybody can see this.